# How to embed films with movie15 and Distiller

Tags: ps2pdf, movie15

The following minimal working example that embeds a film in a pdf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfoutput=0
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[ps2pdf]{hyperref}
\usepackage{movie15}
\begin{document}
Test.
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includemovie[playerid=AAPL_QuickTime,autoplay,controls,repeat,%
text={Anything here}]{10cm}{10cm}%
{/Users/christoph/Desktop/BLF/Films/Ultrafast-camera.mov}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

does not work in the dvi - ps- Distiller route. It compiles in latex, produces ps, but Distiller says:

```
Distilling: minworkex.ps

%%[ Error: undefinedfilename; OffendingCommand: file ]%%

Stack:
(r)

(/Users/christoph/Desktop/BLF/Films/Ultrafast-camera.mov)
{fstream1}
-mark-


%%[ Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%%
%%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%
Distill Time: 0 seconds (00:00:00)
**** End of Job ****
```

To show that nothing obvious is wrong, I add that the pdf is produced correctly if I change the filename to relative and use ps2pdf instead of Distiller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I would like to produce my free downloadable textbook with Distiller in the next edition.

P.S. I know that movie15 is obsolete, but for the time being it seems hard to change the many types of code for the dozens of movies in the tex source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File reading and writing commands in Postscript are considered "unsafe" by current Ghostscript and Distiller versions and produce an error during PS-to-PDF conversion. This default behaviour can be overridden using specific commandline options when running these programs:

```
acrodist /F ...
ps2pdf -dNOSAFER ...
```

http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/Distiller9APIReference.pdf#G4.1503951

http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.19/Use.htm#Other_parameters

Comment: What is the exact command? So far, I use       open -a "/Applications/Adobe Acrobat XI Pro/Acrobat Distiller.app"    /Users/christoph/Desktop/BLF/minworkex.ps   Where does the /F go?

Comment: On my OSX, the command acrodist does not work. There is also no such Option in the Distiller app to be clicked... The manual says to use "Apple Mac OS: AllowPSFileOps user preference" How does one do that?

Comment: As I found out, on OSX, /F or -F is realized by using the "AllowPSFileOps user preference". It requires to edit the plist file. Thank you!